# How to filter set of list based on another set of list?

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array, set, filtering

I have this input:

```java
Set<List<String>> allSafe = new HashSet<>();
Set<List<String>> allErrors = new HashSet<>();
```

How can i filter elements of allErrors based on allSafe? for example if I had:

```
allErrors = [["h","k"],["hi","ho","ha"]]

allSafe = [["h","k"],["sh","ho","ii","oo"],["h","zzz"]]
```

then the expected output should be:

```
filteredAllSafe = [["sh","ii","oo"],["zzz"]]
```

This is my try but it did not work as expected: It returns empty set of list:

```java
public static Set<List<String>> filterSafe(
        Set<List<String>> allSafe,
        Set<List<String>> allErrors) {

    Set<List<String>> filteredSet = allSafe.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.contains(allErrors))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return filteredSet;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<List<String>> allErrors = Set.of(
                List.of("h", "k"),
                List.of("hi", "ho", "ha"));
        Set<List<String>> allSafe = Set.of(
                List.of("h", "k"),
                List.of("sh", "ho", "ii", "oo"),
                List.of("h", "zzz"));
        Set<List<String>> filteredSet = new HashSet<List<String>>();
        boolean found;
        List<String> list;
        for (List<String> safe : allSafe) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String strSafe : safe) {
                found = false;
                for (List<String> error : allErrors) {
                    for (String strError : error) {
                        if (strSafe.equals(strError)) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (found) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    list.add(strSafe);
                }
            }
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                filteredSet.add(list);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(filteredSet);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[sh, ii, oo], [zzz]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using streams where all errors are joined into one Set for simpler filtering

```java
Set<String> errorSet = allErrors.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<List<String>> filteredSet = new HashSet<>();
allSafe.stream().forEach(l -> {
    List<String> filtered = l.stream()
            .filter(e -> !errorSet.contains(e))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (!filtered.isEmpty())
        filteredSet.add(filtered);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first flatten *`allErrors`* to one set and then filter each list from *`allSafe`* so that it doesn't contain any errors:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<List<String>> allErrors = Set.of(
            List.of("h", "k"),
            List.of("hi", "ho", "ha"));

    Set<List<String>> allSafe = Set.of(
            List.of("h", "k"),
            List.of("sh", "ho", "ii", "oo"),
            List.of("h", "zzz"));

    System.out.println(filterSafe(allSafe, allErrors));
    // [[sh, ii, oo], [zzz]]
}
```

```java
public static Set<List<String>> filterSafe(
        Set<List<String>> allSafe,
        Set<List<String>> allErrors) {
    // flatten 'allErrors' into one set
    Set<String> flatErrors = allErrors.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    // return resulting set
    return allSafe.stream()
            .map(list -> list.stream()
                    // each list doesn't contain errors
                    .filter(e -> !flatErrors.contains(e))
                    // list without errors or
                    // empty list if all errors
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            // resulting set doesn't contain empty lists
            .filter(list -> list.size() > 0)
            // resulting set
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```